# Show my App preferences in the Android device settings' view?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an iOS development background. On iPhone, when a user install an app, he can access the app's preferences through the "Settings" menu of iOS. It is really easy to do this on iPhone for a developer.

Is it possible to do something similar on Android easily? Or do Android users are more confortable accessing preferences through the app itself? I'm pretty sure that this is the right answer. But because I don't have a Android background, I would like a confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add your apps preferences to the Android preferences. 
Accessing the preferences through the app is the Android way to modify app specific settings.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation! Just a last question, is there a natural way to access the preference view from the app (tab, menu, button)? Or any method is fine?

Comment: On design decision I suggest you to take a look at the design guide from Google (http://developer.android.com/design) and this in particular, because it is about settings (http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html).

Comment: Thanks! I also like this website, which helped me a lot  http://www.androidpatterns.com/